# CSS image and pseudo element transition out-of-sync

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a transition for both an image and a pseudo element of its container, but for some reason, these transitions appear to be out of sync with each other, resulting in the pseudo element reaching a `opacity: 0` state before the image does.
I've tried various combinations of style rules, but I never managed to accomplish an `ease-in-out` transition to work correctly.

Here's some context for the current code: the image is padded on purpose, to provide a better visual (centered) of its content. The images that'll be used are always guaranteed to have a white background. That's why I'm using a pseudo-element with a white background color to fill the vertical spaces that the image does not cover.
The background-image should take the full width/height of the container and there are not guarantees of its background being white.
The desired effect is for both the pseudo-element and image to reach `opacity: 0` at the same making it look like its a single element.

I'm also considering using an `::after` pseudo element to provide a "loading skeleton" while the image is not retrieved from the server, but that's not a concern for now.

Here's the code, and the respective fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rjk2z31d/1/

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  width: 248px;
  height: 320px;
}

.image-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;

  &::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: (100% + (100% / 3));
  }

  img {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    padding: 16px 16px;
  }

  &::before, img {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  &:hover {
    &::before, img {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="image-box" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/248x320/FF0000/000000?text=Background')">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/248x320/FFFFFF/000000?text=Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, they both fade at the same speed.
The out-of-sync effect you're talking about is an illusion due to the opacities overlapping.

If you set the initial opacity of both elements, it's easier to understand what's going on.

**The image's faded white added to the pseudo element's faded white looks less transparent than the pseudo element's faded white alone.**

See it in effect with the below image:

[image]

If you need to be convinced of their synchronization, add a transform rule to the :hover handler. the result is synced as it is supposed to be.

As a workaround, I would suggest you to try figuring out a better approach than fading overlapping elements.
You could use the `<picture>` tag with css `object-fit` property to get rid of those blank spaces.

[picture doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

[object-fit doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: Thanks for your help on clarifying this. I was so convinced that there was something wrong with the way animations were being handled, I never thought the items opacity overlapping would end up causing this effect. I ended up solving this problem by adding a container around the image and applying the opacity effect there.